# Crear método genérico en java

Tags: java, genericos

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Tengo una clase `Dato` con la siguiente definición:

```
public String name;
public Integer number; 
public string date;
```

Y otra del mismo nombre y con la misma definición:

```
public String name;
public Integer number; 
public Date date;
```

Se llaman igual por que son clases de packages distintos de acuerdo al OSB del que provienen.

Mi problema es que quiero crear un metodo generico para transformar cada uno de los atributos del objeto (Dato) a String, sin tener que repetir el código.

Comment: Cabe resaltar que cada objeto "Dato" tiene una ubicación distinta, por lo que no los puedo tratar como el mismo objeto.

Comment: ¿Y de qué manera pasas los parámetros del método? ¿Lo haces directamente para cada atributo? Por ejemplo, si tienes 3 atributos de tipo: String, Integer y String; ¿el método lo haces con los parámetros de tipo String, Integer y String?

Comment: Lo hago de la siguiente manera: public void pasarParametros(Object ibject)

Comment: Creo que vas a tener que hacer uso de la reflexión. Es la mejor opción si tienes que acceder a los datos de diferentes tipos de objetos, y en dependencia del tipo de cada dato tratarlo como debas. Yo la utilizara si tienes que manipular un número grande y/o variable de tipos objetos, pero igual si solo son dos no vale la pena, ya que vas a escribir bastante código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A menos que puedas modificar ambas clases para que compartan una misma interfaz o supertipo tendras que repetir el codigo para manejar las instancias de uno u otro tipo. Por ejemplo:

```
public interface InterfazComun {
    String getName();
    Integer getNumber();
    Date getDate();
}
```

Clases datos (con package distintos):

```
package uno;
public class Dato implements InterfazComun {
    private String name;
    private Integer number;
    private Date date;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

}
```

Uso en algun metodo comun:

```
void utilizar(InterfazComun dato) {
    String name = dato.getName();
    Integer number = dato.getNumber();
    Date date = dato.getDate();
}
```